# Access tag name li from an ul block

Tags: javascript

I want to show an alert when I click on "aaa" or "bbb" .How can I access li elements without the class "click" from the ul with the id = parent ?  For the other elements I used :

```
var elements = document.getElementById('parent');
var classElem = document.getElementsByClassName('click');
```

I thought of something like :`liW = elements - classElem` but this doesn't work.

This is the html I used :

```
<html> 
<head>
</head>
<body> <ul id = "parent"> 
<li> aaa </li>
<li> bbb </li>
<li class ="click"> ccc </li>
<li class ="click"> ddd </li> 
</ul> 
<ul> <li> eee </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.filter`, like so:

```
var liW = [].filter.call(
    document.getElementById('parent').children, // the LI elements
    function(li) {return !li.classList.contains('click');}
);
```

This will give you an array of nodes corresponding to the `<li>` tags that do *not* have `class="click"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by looping through all the child `li` elements, checking if each of them has the class `click`, and if not, make the alert show up when clicked.

```
var elements = document.getElementById('parent').getElementsByTagName('li');
function elementClicked(elem) {
    alert('test');
}
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if(!elements[i].classList.contains('click')) {
        elementClicked(elements[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems awfully specific, when the question was about selecting elements that don't have a class...

Comment: You've completely changed your answer :p Fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the event listener on the parent element - the UL -
and check if the target element has the class.

example -

```
list = document.getElementById('parent');

list.addEventListener('click',function(e){
    if (e.target.className.indexOf('click') === -1) alert(test);
});
```